# Word Print Preview not honoring my SSRS format settings

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

```
    <InteractiveHeight>11in</InteractiveHeight>
    <InteractiveWidth>8.5in</InteractiveWidth>
    <LeftMargin>1in</LeftMargin>
    <RightMargin>1in</RightMargin>
    <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
    <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>
```

When I print preview after exporting it to word:
Custom Page Size 10.36" x 11"
My margins are fine, but the wording goes off the page and gets cut off.

Is there any way to force the page size to be 8.5x11?

Answer (score 0):

Check if some of the elements are wider than thr max width. Usually when I have this issue it turns out that a page header/footer/tablix is a few milimeters longer than it should. Also, check if the content AND the margins fit in the dimension for the word page you want.

Comment: Thanks yes I had some tables that were larger and fixed it